# How to Enable Button on certain boolean condition in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, button, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to enable the button in flutter application on certain boolean condition which is derived from the firestore document. In the below code shared  function `checkTrueFalse()` should be called and the `bool` values of `checkFinalValue1` and `checkFinalValue2` should be derived and if `checkFinalValue1` is `true` then `Button1` should give result on being pressed, and if `checkFinalValue2` is `true` then `Button2` should be enabled otherwise it should appear disabled.

How can we do this in flutter application? I am not able find `Flatbutton` properties of `enable button` as we have it in Android Studio or Xcode

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String listid1 = widget.listid1;
    bool checkFinalValue1, checkFinalValue2;


  checkTrueFalse() { final DocumentReference docRef =  Firestore.instance.collection("list").document(listid1);


    docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
      checkFinalValue1 = ds.data["value1"];
      checkFinalValue2 = ds.data["value2"];

       });}

       final button1 = FlatButton();
    return Card(child: ListTile(title:Text(widget.itemTitle),subtitle: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(widget.commentId),
        Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Button1"),
                  onPressed: () {

                  print("Check 1");


                  },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Button2"),
                  onPressed: () { 

                    print("Button Enabled");

                  },
                ),
              ],
            ))
      ],
    ), ),);

  }
```

Comment: So you want to hide button or disable it?

Comment: @jitsm555 I want to disable `Button2` initially but if the value of `checkFinalValue2` is `true` then the button should be enabled, but for `Button1` the action called should be only if the `checkFinalValue1` is true, but `Button1` should be enabled always

Comment: for disabling button , you can set onPressed function to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Flat Button Like

```
      FlatButton(
                child: Text("Button1"),
                onPressed: checkFinalValue1
                    ? () {
                        print("Check 1");
                      }
                    : null),

            FlatButton(
                child: Text("Button2"),
                onPressed: checkFinalValue2
                    ? () {
                        print("Button Enabled");

                      }
                    : null),
```

Comment: the values of `checkFinalValue1` and `checkFinalValue2` will be available when the function `checkTrueFalse()` is called, how should it be called?

Comment: you have to call it from somewhere else, like initState() or any widget click